# Questions about Random and Int (Java)

Tags: java, random

Assuming I generate a random number between 1-10, how do I use the random number generated into a for loop? Is there a way to convert random to int?

```
public class CityTravelerApp {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    // TODO code application logic here

    Queue myQueue= new Queue(80);

    //a. Generate a random number called num between 1 and 10, inclusive. 
    Random number = new Random();
    System.out.println(number.nextInt(10)+1);


    for(int i =1;i<=number;i++){
        System.out.println("Enter the name of country #" + i);
        String name = input.next();
    }


    }
```

Comment: I don't understand. The `Random#nextInt` method returns an `int`. What are you asking?

Comment: I can't use the variable number which is the random number generated. It gives me an error

Comment: `Random ` is not a number, is a number generator, used to generate numbers. Actually in the first `System.out.println` you've used it correctly, but in the loop you didn't

Comment: Just store number.nextInte(10)+1 in an int variable. For example: int randNumber = number.nextInte(10)+1;

Comment: number = new Random(); your variable is not storing the random value rather the generator itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`number` is `Random` `Object` which you can not use in loop for comparing it with `int` `i`, instead store result of `number.nextInt` to some `int` variable and use that variable in `for` loop. Basically, you can not compare `int` with `Random`, because both types are *incompatible*.

```
Random number = new Random();
int limit = number.nextInt(10) + 1;

for(int i = 1; i <= limit; i++){
   ...
}
```